# Swing controls button not showing in NetBeans DROP DOWN

Tags: swing, netbeans

[image: Not showing normal BUTTON in swing controls]

How to get GUI based normal Button in this pic

Answer (score 2):

[image]

right click on swing controls and click on Reset palette . Thats it :)